# JQuery - Why this code to load an image from an external url not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
function applyimage(str){
   console.log("in apply image function");
   var url = 'base_url' + str ;
   url = ' url("' + url + '") ';
   console.log(url);
   $('.jumbotron').css({
    "background-image" : "url",
    "background-size" : "cover",
    "height" : "100%",
 });
```

When I log url into console it shows me the correct link. However this is not working.!

Comment: You're `background-image` is set to a string called URL... not your variable URL

Comment: function applyimage(str){
    console.log("in apply image function");
    var url = 'base_url' + str ;
    url = ' url("' + url + '") ';
    console.log(url);
    $('.jumbotron').css({
        "background-image" : url, //this not to be string
        "background-size" : "cover",
        "height" : "100%",
}); Hope this helps!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not add `""` while you're using variable value

Code:

```
function applyimage(str){
    console.log("in apply image function");
    var url = 'base_url' + str ;
    url = ' url("' + url + '") ';
    console.log(url);
    $('.jumbotron').css({
        "background-image" : url,
        "background-size" : "cover",
        "height" : "100%",
});
```

When You write something in double quotes it means it will parse that as a string not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with one more solution using `ES6` template literals

```
function applyimage(str){ 
  $('.jumbotron').css({
    "background-image" : `url("base_url${str}")`,
    "background-size" : "cover",
    "height" : "100%",
  });
}
```

Your problem was in `"background-image" : "url",`.

Hope this will help you to solve the problem.